# react native push notification snooze (react-native-push-notification)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification for local push notifications. It also includes an option to have some buttons on the notification("actions"), which I can press on.

However, when I'm getting a notification, to respond to that button(noti. action), the app should open(the only way I could work it around) and only then I can run my logic according to the action.

Because I have some troubles using react-native-push-notification for this(It simply doesn't work), I would like to implement this by myself.

This is the process I wish to have:

1. Push notification is showing up
2. The user clicks on the snooze button(same as an alarm)
3. The application is still in the background
4. The notification will be pushed again after some time.

What is the proper way to do such a thing? I have to run a background task that is fired when the user presses the snooze button. How can I use HeadlessJS for this? It is very easy to implement the snoozing logic with JavaScript, the problem is to fire it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use another library for this, the [notifee](https://github.com/invertase/notifee) library.

According to [this](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/interaction) page on the docs, you can create like this:

```js
//[...]

notifee.displayNotification({
  title: '08:00am Alarm',
  body: 'The alarm you set for 08:00am requires attention!',
  android: {
    channelId: 'alarms',
    actions: [
      {
        title: 'Snooze',
        icon: 'https://my-cdn.com/icons/snooze.png',
        pressAction: {
          id: 'snooze'
        },
      },
      {
        title: 'not snooze',
        icon: 'https://my-cdn.com/icons/notSnooze.png',
        pressAction: {
          id: 'snooze',
          launchActivity: 'com.awesome.app.CustomActivity',
          launchActivityFlags: []
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});

//[...]
```

### Explanation

On the `actions` array, you can either provide your activity, to open your app, and use launchActivityFlags to send some parameters to the application (Like in the `not snooze` action).

Or, you can provide nothing, and then the app would not open, and then, you would need to use a listener to the background/foreground event, like as follows:

```
import notifee, { EventType } from '@notifee/react-native';
//[...]
notifee.onForegroundEvent(({ type, detail }) => {
  if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && detail.pressAction.id) {
    console.log('User pressed an action with the id: ', detail.pressAction.id);
    //Use your code here to send your notification again after some time
  }
//[...]
```

You can see more about notifications actions on [this](https://notifee.app/react-native/reference/notificationpressaction) documentation.

And you can see some code on [this](https://github.com/invertase/notifee/tree/main/packages/react-native/example) example app provided by notifee themselves.

IF, you're looking for an alarm clock application, I found [this](https://github.com/bartolomej/rn-alarm) app, but as it looks like, it doesn't provide a notification, so it might not be that much helpful.

[EDIT]

To run a piece of code if the user dismissed the notification (He didn't answer it in time, or swiped it right away), you can use the same concept of the `onForegroundEvent`, but with some changes, like as follows:

```
import notifee, { EventType } from '@notifee/react-native';

const timeout = false

//[...]

notifee.onForegroundEvent(({ type, detail }) => {
  
  if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)

  if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && detail.pressAction.id){    
    console.log('User pressed an action with the id: ', detail.pressAction.id);
    //Use your code here to send your notification again after some time
  
  } else if (type === EventType.DISMISSED){    
    console.log('User dismissed the notification');
    //Use your code here to send your notification again after some time, or maybe another action if the user dismissed the notification

  } else if ([EventType.APP_BLOCKED, EventType.CHANNEL_BLOCKED, EventType.CHANNEL_GROUP_BLOCKED].includes(type)){
    console.log("User cannot receive notification because the app is blocked")
    //Run your code to tell the user that he needs to unblock notifications here.

  } else if (type === EventType.DELIVERED){
    console.log("Notification was delivered")
    
    timeout = setTimeout(async () => {
      console.log("Counting down the notification timeout")
      //Run here your code to snooze the app if the user lost the notificaiton
    }, 60000)

  } else if (type === EventType.UNKNOWN){
    console.log("Unknown error happened with the notification")
    //Run your failsafe code here
  }
//[...]
```

### Explanation

According to the docs:

> DISMISSED: Event type is sent when the user dismisses a notification. This is triggered via the user swiping the notification from the notification shade or performing "Clear all" notifications.
> This event is not sent when a notification is cancelled or times out.

Since this event is not sent when a notification is cancelled or timed out, and I cannot try for myself and tell you what is the event type for that case, I made a timeout count down the notification timeout with the `EVENT.DELIVERED`, and if nothing happens, then you can run the code to snooze the alarm.

> DELIVERED: Event type sent when a notification has been delivered to the device. For trigger notifications, this event is sent at the point when the trigger executes, not when the trigger notification is created.

It's important to note even though a notification has been delivered, it may not be shown to the user. For example, they may have notifications disabled on the device/channel/app.

The countdown time will need some change to adapt to your use case (If the timeout is something dynamic, would require some more code to set it on that function).

The timeout code might not be required if there's a different event for when the notification times out, but as I read on the docs, that's not the case.

I also used the `UNKNOWN` event type as a failsafe, and the `APP_BLOCKED`, `CHANNEL_BLOCKED`, `CHANNEL_GROUP_BLOCKED` to see if the notification can be delivered to the user:

> UNKNOWN: An unknown event was received. This event type is a failsafe to catch any unknown events from the device. Please report an issue with a reproduction so it can be correctly handled.

> APP_BLOCKED: Event is sent when the user changes the notification blocked state for the entire application or when the user opens the application settings.

> CHANNEL_BLOCKED: Event type is sent when the user changes the notification blocked state for a channel in the application.

> CHANNEL_GROUP_BLOCKED : Event type is sent when the user changes the notification blocked state for a channel group in the application.

You can read more about the event types on [this](https://notifee.app/react-native/reference/eventtype#dismissed) page on the docs.

Comment: In native android alarm soonze works without any action, that is the requirement, otherwise using actions (user interaction) its easy to do with other libraries as well.

Comment: Oh, no problem, I will update my answer to include an event type that helps.
One minute.

Comment: @Sami Done! Hope it helps.

Comment: Super effort boss, but I am sorry, its still depending upon some event (user interaction)



btw you explained all except `EventType.DELIVERED` which might be the only thing which would do something in case user missed the notification (e.g) user applied a ringtone of 20 seconds, did not wake up now how can I make app to notify again after 10 minutes (or user choice interval =>chosen at the time of creation).

Comment: I am talking about the only case when user did not respond, and app is supposed to remind later n times with x interval

Comment: I thought so, that's why I made the code able to differentiate between the "user dismissed the notification by swiping" and "the user didn't answer the notification".


So you could increment a counter and send a notification after some interval of time, and check every time if the counter is below or equal to the limit. (As you pointed before).


Also included the `delivered` event into the answer.


Hope it helps!
Thank you btw.